# msbuild can't find references in projects.assets.json

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, .net-standard

I have a .net standard library project targeting .net standard 2.0 and I'm trying to build it in VSTS using MSBuild, the build server where the build agent is installed doesn't have internet access so I copied the dependencies to the C:\users\username.nuget\packages folder however MSBuild fails saying "Netsdk1064, Package microsoft.csharp, version 4.3.0 was not found".
I've tried copying the dependencies on the packages folder of the solution but still now working. I can't use Nuget restore on the build server so I was wondering if there is a way to redirect project.assets.json to look in the folder I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if package `Netsdk1064, Package microsoft.csharp` successfully copied in `C:\users\username\.nuget\packages folder`, since it errored this package was not found.

As workaround, you can create a nuget.config file and commit to your repo. And add the local directory where the all your packages reside under the `packageSources` element of nuget.config file. See below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="local" value="C:\users\username\.nuget\packages" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Check [Package source sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections) of nuget.config for more information.

Then you can use nuget restore task to restore the packages. And Set `nugetConfigPath` point to the nuget.config created above.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: 'SmartFuel.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

If the nuget restore task failed to restore from the local package source. Please check the nuget version used in your pipeline. If the nuget version is 4.1.0 or older. You need to use [NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) to use a higher versions of nuget. See [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/841179/azure-pipelines-fails-to-restore-packages-from-loc.html) for more information.

Another possible workaround is to edit the .csproj file and manually point the referenced package to the .dll in local folder using `hintpath`. For example below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DependPackage">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\package\DependPackage.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```